# Pandas: How to make pivot table keeping the original rows order?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

| ...(index) | category | segment | ytd2018 | ytd2019 | Evolution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Abcd | Online | 10742936.6 | 12150003.8 | 13.1% |
| 14 | AMG | Online | 1501003.0 | 1666728.3 | 11.0% |
| 2 | LEP | Offline | 22515733.3 | 25783157.9 | 14.5% |
| 11 | AMG | Offline | 8451094.8 | 10498181.7 | 24.2% |
| 3 | Perq | Offline | 2865522.5 | 3487813.1 | 21.7% |
| 12 | AMG | Offline | 1211140.9 | 1669279.0 | 37.8% |
| 4 | Lio | Online | 1238761.4 | 990406.4 | -20.0% |
| 13 | AMG | Online | 1101728.3 | 885455.7 | -19.6% |
| 1 | HEPT | Offline | 9754877.7 | 11461190.1 | 17.5% |
| 10 | AMG | Offline | 2228371.4 | 3242144.4 | 45.5% |
| 7 | Slid | Online | 5837929.8 | 11159962.2 | 91.2% |
| 16 | AMG | Offline | 1178883.7 | 2733493.8 | 131.9% |
| 0 | NPD | Online | 2435918.4 | 3150325.3 | 29.3% |

*I have sorted the dataset, so AMG is subcategory, e.g. under Lio, the originally AMG was AMG Lio, so I deleted the second word

I want to have the following output:
[image: output]

**Right in that order from the dataset. It's important the original data sequence of `category` be retained.**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
(df.reset_index(drop=True)
   .set_index(['category', 'segment'], append=True)
   .unstack()
   .swaplevel(axis=1)
   .sort_index(level=0, axis=1, ascending=False)
   .reindex(['ytd2018', 'ytd2019', 'Evolution'], level=1, axis=1)
#   .sort_index(level=0, axis=0)
)
```

**Result:**

```
segment          Online                           Offline                      
                ytd2018     ytd2019 Evolution     ytd2018     ytd2019 Evolution
   category                                                                    
0  Abcd      10742936.6  12150003.8     13.1%         NaN         NaN       NaN
1  AMG        1501003.0   1666728.3     11.0%         NaN         NaN       NaN
2  LEP              NaN         NaN       NaN  22515733.3  25783157.9     14.5%
3  AMG              NaN         NaN       NaN   8451094.8  10498181.7     24.2%
4  Perq             NaN         NaN       NaN   2865522.5   3487813.1     21.7%
5  AMG              NaN         NaN       NaN   1211140.9   1669279.0     37.8%
6  Lio        1238761.4    990406.4    -20.0%         NaN         NaN       NaN
7  AMG        1101728.3    885455.7    -19.6%         NaN         NaN       NaN
8  HEPT             NaN         NaN       NaN   9754877.7  11461190.1     17.5%
9  AMG              NaN         NaN       NaN   2228371.4   3242144.4     45.5%
10 Slid       5837929.8  11159962.2     91.2%         NaN         NaN       NaN
11 AMG              NaN         NaN       NaN   1178883.7   2733493.8    131.9%
12 NPD        2435918.4   3150325.3     29.3%         NaN         NaN       NaN
```

Comment: I need to leave the order of rows, so after NPD, HEPT etc. should be its AMG.

Comment: And that is actually the main problem :(

Comment: @nikita1221   Ok, commented out the sorting on `category`.  Take a look.

Comment: @nikita1221  Further fine-tuned a bit.  Original rows order maintained.

Comment: Btw, do you think it is possible to save it as excel file without index? I tried index=False, but recieved mistake

Comment: @nikita1221  Currently, the resulting dataframe have 2 levels of row index:  one is the so called RangeIndex of 0, 1, 2, ...12.  The other index is the `category`.  If you want to write it to Excel with this `category` but without the RangeIndex.  You can relocate `category` from the index back to data column first.  You can do this by attaching the code `.reset_index(-1)` at the end of the codes above.

Comment: @nikita1221  `.reset_index('category')`  also works for this.  You can use either this or `.reset_index(-1)`

Comment: @nikita1221  After this, write to Excel with `index=False` as you tried before.

Comment: I did as you wrote, but still got Writing to Excel with MultiIndex columns and no index ('index'=False) is not yet implemented.

Comment: @nikita1221  Result with MultiIndex columns (column not row) is normal since you require the layout of `Online` / `Offline` in one (column) level and the labels `\ytd2018     ytd2019 Evolution` in another level.  Isn't this what you wanted ?

Comment: yes, thank you, it was nice solution, I just wonder if it is possible to write the df into excel without indexes :)

Comment: @nikita1221  You want to write to Excel without row index or column index ?  If without column index (labels), you can try with the parm `header=False`.  Anyway, I seldom write without header.  You can just try.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work :( Btw, I also wanted to ask, if there will be values, for example LEP in Online and Offline segments, how can I make the same table, but without duplicate rows for segments? Your code prints 2 rows with LEP: LEP online with null values in offline segment and LEP offline with null values in online segment. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @nikita1221  For the case of writing the df into excel with indexes, if you mean row index,  you have already tried `index=False` and if you mean column index / label, you have also tried `header=False`.  These are the 2 ways to skipping writing the 'index'.  If both doesn't work, it needs more detailed work on that.   As this part about writing to Excel is not related to your original question, suggest you post another question on it or search existing answers for that.  If I see the question, I will also take a look with the details and see whether can solve it.

Comment: @nikita1221  For the 2nd question about LEP with  Online and Offline segments and you want to do some kind of `consolidation` into one segment ?  I'm afraid it also needs more details about what you want to do.  It's not a good place to discuss and give solution in comments with all the details.  Would you also post more details in a new question ?

Comment: Yes, I have created new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68996306/how-to-create-this-table-from-sorted-dataframe/68996937?noredirect=1#comment121949553_68996937

Comment: @nikita1221  I just checked your new question. The solution provided by ThePyGuy is using based on my code to add 2 lines to aggregate the lines with `NaN` entries into 1 line.  This doesn't work for you ?   Is it that that solution removed row 5 on the second line of MUP Online which has also one line of the same MUP Online above it ?   You want to keep both lines of MUP Online ?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it prints rows category in totally different order, but aggregates lines into 1 row. I want to keep only 1 line with e.g. MUP online, but with values in all segments

Comment: @nikita1221  I see that solution can maintain the order as `HC`, `AMG HC`, `MUP`, `AMG MUP`, `S`, `AMG S` each one with one line. `HC` has all values of Online, Offline, Independent.  This still not what you want ?   I can see the only problem is that it removed the second line of `MUP` ONLINE, since there are 2 lines of this with different values `2 000 1 800 -10%` and `1 200 1 080 -10%`

Comment: That is what I want, but this code prints output in desc alphabetical order, doesn't remain the same order

Comment: @nikita1221  I can try working to keep your desired order.  However, I want to clarify whether you want one line or 2 lines of `MUP ONLINE` in the sample data.  As I said there are 2 lines with different values `2 000 1 800 -10%` and `1 200 1 080 -10%`, you want to keep only the FIRST line or have to keep BOTH lines ?

Comment: @nikita1221   I've added a solution to your new question.  Take a look and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @nikita1221  Pleased to help!   I worked on your original question and thus know more special characteristic of your dataset.  Hence, can solve it more readily.