# How to create this table from sorted dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have sorted the dataframe and now I would like to create this table:
[image: output]

Sample of data:

```
df4 = {'category': {0: 'HC', 1: 'HC', 2: 'HC', 3: 'AMG HC', 4: 'MUP', 5: 'MUP', 6: 'AMG MUP', 7: 'AMG MUP', 8: 'AMG MUP', 9: 'S', 10: 'S', 11: 'AMG S', 12: 'AMG S'}, 'segment': {0: 'Online', 1: 'Offline', 2: 'Independent', 3: 'Online', 4: 'Online', 5: 'Online', 6: 'Online', 7: 'Offline', 8: 'Independent', 9: 'Online', 10: 'Offline', 11: 'Online', 12: 'Offline'}, 'ytd2018': {0: '1 000', 1: '3 000', 2: '800', 3: '500', 4: '2 000', 5: '1 200', 6: '500', 7: '1 020', 8: '310', 9: '1 500', 10: '2 300', 11: '400', 12: '1 080'}, 'ytd2019': {0: '1 100', 1: '2 800', 2: '920', 3: '450', 4: '1 800', 5: '1 080', 6: '600', 7: '1 020', 8: '440', 9: '2 000', 10: '2 200', 11: '650', 12: '1 100'}, 'Evolution': {0: '10%', 1: '-7%', 2: '15%', 3: '-10%', 4: '-10%', 5: '-10%', 6: '20%', 7: '0%', 8: '42%', 9: '33%', 10: '-4%', 11: '63%', 12: '2%'}}
```

Note: I have formated columns Evolution, ytd2018 and ytd2019, so they are strings

I have tried this code:

```
df4 = (df4.reset_index(drop=True)
   .set_index(['category', 'segment'], append=True)
   .unstack()
   .swaplevel(axis=1)
   .sort_index(level=0, axis=1, ascending=False)
   .reindex(['ytd2018, 'ytd2019', 'Evolution'], level=1, axis=1)
#   .sort_index(level=0, axis=0)
)
```

But it prints duplicate rows with null values in segments, e.g. HC online without offline and independent, then HC offline without online and independent etc.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
df5 = (df4.reset_index(drop=True)
          .set_index(['category', 'segment'], append=True)
          .unstack()
          .swaplevel(axis=1)
          .sort_index(level=0, axis=1, ascending=False)
          .reindex(['ytd2018', 'ytd2019', 'Evolution'], level=1, axis=1)
      )

df6 = df5.groupby(level='category', sort=False).first()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df6)



segment   Online                   Offline                   Independent                  
         ytd2018 ytd2019 Evolution ytd2018 ytd2019 Evolution     ytd2018 ytd2019 Evolution
category                                                                                  
HC         1 000   1 100       10%   3 000   2 800       -7%         800     920       15%
AMG HC       500     450      -10%    None    None      None        None    None      None
MUP        2 000   1 800      -10%    None    None      None        None    None      None
AMG MUP      500     600       20%   1 020   1 020        0%         310     440       42%
S          1 500   2 000       33%   2 300   2 200       -4%        None    None      None
AMG S        400     650       63%   1 080   1 100        2%        None    None      None
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! For this dataset it worked perfectly, but I got stuck with the problem that it prints segments in descending order :( I have custom dictionary, that sorts segments. Could you please advice me how to fix it?

Comment: @nikita1221   You can remove the code `.sort_index(level=0, axis=1, ascending=False)` above and replace with your code that sort segments.

Comment: Well before I sorted 2 columns: `order = {'category': custom_dict, 'segment': custom_dict2}` and `df4 = df4.sort_values(['category', 'segment'], key=lambda s: s.map(order[s.name]))`

Comment: @nikita1221  You don't follow the solution you accepted using `pd.Categorical` in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68982887/how-to-sort-dataset-based-on-2-custom-lists) and pick another solution ?    If you think that another solution better, probably you should accept this another solution instead in that question

Comment: I tried both and they worked, I tested the solution from Shubhan secondly and it just remained

Comment: I accepted the second one, because I used it :)

Comment: @nikita1221  The structure of the dataframe in that question is different from that here.  Here, we have category in row index rather than data column in that question.  If the sequence of `category` in this question is already fine and you don't need to sort it again, you can modify that solution to sort only the segment.  However, the column index structures of the 2 questions are still different.  Here is 2 levels with Online, Offline, etc.  In that question, only one row.  You got to further customize for this.

Comment: Well because in that question I wanted to sort the values by 2 custom dictionaries, but here I wanted to ask how to create the output table from question that remains the order from given dataframe

Comment: I have edited the code: ` df5 = (df4.reset_index(drop=True)
          .set_index(['category', 'segment'], append=True)
          .unstack()
          .swaplevel(axis=1)
          .sort_values(['category', 'segment'], key=lambda s: s.map(order[s.name]))
          .reindex(['ytd2018', 'ytd2019', 'Evolution'], level=1, axis=1)
      ) ` But recieved key error 'segment'

Comment: @nikita1221 With further thought, the solution in that other solution is not applicable to your case here.  In that solution, you sort on the data column. Now, you want to sort the column index.  In particular, you are going to rearrange on the Online/Offline/Independent column label.  In this case, you can solve it by doing what's similar in my solution above on using `reindex`  Just add one more `reindex` above the current one, replace the list of label e.g. `ytd2018` ... with the list of Online/Offline/Independent  in your required sequence.  And remember to use `level=0` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Group the result at last by `level=1`, then call `first` to get the required result:

```py
>>>  (df4.set_index(['category', 'segment'], append=True)
         .unstack()
         .swaplevel(axis=1)
         .sort_index(level=0, axis=1, ascending=False)
         .reindex(['ytd2018', 'ytd2019', 'Evolution'], level=1, axis=1)
         .groupby(level=1, sort=False)
         .first()
         )
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
segment   Online                   Offline                   Independent  \
         ytd2018 ytd2019 Evolution ytd2018 ytd2019 Evolution     ytd2018   
category                                                                   
HC         1 000   1 100       10%   3 000   2 800       -7%         800   
AMG HC       500     450      -10%    None    None      None        None   
MUP        2 000   1 800      -10%    None    None      None        None   
AMG MUP      500     600       20%   1 020   1 020        0%         310   
S          1 500   2 000       33%   2 300   2 200       -4%        None   
AMG S        400     650       63%   1 080   1 100        2%        None   
segment                     
         ytd2019 Evolution  
category                    
HC           920       15%  
AMG HC      None      None  
MUP         None      None  
AMG MUP      440       42%  
S           None      None  
AMG S       None      None
```

Comment: Thank you for solution, but it prints the result in alphabetical order. I would like to keep the same order, because before I have sorted the list. Can you please advice me how to do it?

Comment: pass `sort` as `False`

Comment: you mean in sort_index?

Comment: passiing `sort=False` to `groupby`

Comment: It doesn't work :( It prints in totally different order

Comment: @nikita1221, you can see the output in the solution I have provided, isn't it the one you are looking for?

Comment: yes, it looks exactly what I wanted, but may be because of index it doesn't print the proper result? It prints desc alphabetically

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot_table` with `first` as aggregation function:

```
(df4.pivot_table(index='category',
                 columns='segment',
                 values=['ytd2018', 'ytd2019', 'Evolution'],
                 aggfunc='first')
    .swaplevel(axis=1)
    .sort_index(level=0, axis=1, ascending=False)
    .reindex(['ytd2018', 'ytd2019', 'Evolution'], level=1, axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
segment   Online                   Offline                   Independent                  
         ytd2018 ytd2019 Evolution ytd2018 ytd2019 Evolution     ytd2018 ytd2019 Evolution
category                                                                                  
AMG HC       500     450      -10%     NaN     NaN       NaN         NaN     NaN       NaN
AMG MUP      500     600       20%   1 020   1 020        0%         310     440       42%
AMG S        400     650       63%   1 080   1 100        2%         NaN     NaN       NaN
HC         1 000   1 100       10%   3 000   2 800       -7%         800     920       15%
MUP        2 000   1 800      -10%     NaN     NaN       NaN         NaN     NaN       NaN
S          1 500   2 000       33%   2 300   2 200       -4%         NaN     NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for solution, but I would like to print everything in my own order, not alphabetically. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: @nikita1221 yes, but I think [I already answered this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68983714/16343464) to another of your questions, right? Use the same approach

Comment: Yes, I remember, I used your code and got sorted dataset, but how to connect these 2 solutions?